# Adding a column to a Dataframe containing the Symbol of the parent node

Tags: python, pandas, tree

I am using bulk data (List of CPC Valid symbols) from the [CPC website](https://www.cooperativepatentclassification.org/cpcSchemeAndDefinitions/Bulk.html). I've read the csv into a pandas df, and the first 30 rows (of over 260K) are:

```
    SYMBOL  level   not-allocatable additional-only
1   A   2   True    False
2   A01 4   True    False
3   A01B    5   True    False
4   A01B 1/00   7   False   False
5   A01B 1/02   8   False   False
6   A01B 1/022  9   False   False
7   A01B 1/024  9   False   False
8   A01B 1/026  9   False   False
9   A01B 1/028  9   False   False
10  A01B 1/04   9   False   False
11  A01B 1/06   8   False   False
12  A01B 1/065  9   False   False
13  A01B 1/08   9   False   False
14  A01B 1/10   9   False   False
15  A01B 1/12   9   False   False
16  A01B 1/14   9   False   False
17  A01B 1/16   8   False   False
18  A01B 1/165  9   False   False
19  A01B 1/18   9   False   False
20  A01B 1/20   8   False   False
21  A01B 1/22   8   False   False
22  A01B 1/222  9   False   False
23  A01B 1/225  10  False   False
24  A01B 1/227  9   False   False
25  A01B 1/24   8   False   False
26  A01B 1/243  9   False   False
27  A01B 1/246  9   False   False
28  A01B 3/00   7   False   False
29  A01B 3/02   8   False   False
```

The level value creates a hierarchy. So node A01B 1/00 is level 7 and a child of A01B. A01B 1/02 is level 8 and the child of A01B 1/00 & A01b 3/00 is a child of A01B.

What I would like is a way to create a new column called `PARENT` that contains the `SYMBOL` of the node's direct parent. For example, I edited the csv in Excel to show the desired result of the first few rows:

[image: The dataframe after adding the parent column]

> **Note**: there are no level 1, 3, or 6 symbols. There are multiple level 2 symbols. There is no parent for level 2 symbols, the parent of level 4 symbols can be assigned the first level 2 symbol above it, and the parent of level 7 symbols likewise can be assigned the first level 5 symbol above it.

EDIT: I need to better explain how to determine a node's parent. The level value and the row position are all that is needed to determine a parent.[image: Tree showing parents and children]

I would like to use pandas to do the work, but I am not sure how to get started. Any takers? Thank you

Comment: "row 5 (A01B 1/02) would have index value 4 for the value in the Parent column" - but parent of row 5 has index 3. Isn't it?

Comment: @Supratim Haldar, I see what you mean, parent of index 5 is index 4. Index 5 is level 8 & index 4 is level 7. it doesn't really matter what the symbol is, the only thing that matters is the level and the position of the row to determine hierarchy.

Comment: May be it's only me, but the logic of determining parent is not clear. I thought the first part of `symbol` determines parent (like "A01B" is parent of "A01B 1/00"). But you mentioned that symbol does not matter. Can you please explain clearly the logic and update your question?

Comment: @SupratimHaldar I added a diagram that shows the hierarchy. hope this helps.

Comment: What about downloading the [pre-linked data](https://www.cooperativepatentclassification.org/cpcSchemeAndDefinitions/CPCopenLinkedData.html) and then parsing it with [rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib)?

Comment: hmm, not sure. Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another method.  GetParent() returns a function that keeps track of the most recent symbol for each level and returns the parent of the current level.  Using it in pandas.apply() creates a column with the parent symbols.

```
def GetParent():
    #            0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
    hierarchy = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 5, 7, 8, 9]
    parent = [' ']*11

    def func(row):
        #print(row)
        symbol,level = row[['SYMBOL', 'level']]

        parent_level = hierarchy[level]
        parent_symbol = parent[parent_level]

        parent[level] = symbol

        return pd.Series([parent_symbol], index=['parent'])

    return func

# create a column with the parents
parents = df.apply(GetParent(), axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df, parents], axis=1)

df
```

Output:

```
    SYMBOL  level   na      ao      parent
0   A           2   True    False   
1   A01         4   True    False   A
2   A01B        5   True    False   A01
3   A01B 1/00   7   False   False   A01B
4   A01B 1/02   8   False   False   A01B 1/00
5   A01B 1/022  9   False   False   A01B 1/02
6   A01B 1/024  9   False   False   A01B 1/02
7   A01B 1/026  9   False   False   A01B 1/02
8   A01B 1/028  9   False   False   A01B 1/02
9   A01B 1/04   9   False   False   A01B 1/02
10  A01B 1/06   8   False   False   A01B 1/00
11  A01B 1/065  9   False   False   A01B 1/06
12  A01B 1/08   9   False   False   A01B 1/06
...
```

Comment: Interesting. There the highest level symbols is 19. Can you explain the values in hierarchy and how I would modify it to process the entire file?

Comment: Alright, figured it out. This solution is many times faster. Thank you! `hierarchy = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]`
`parent = [' ']*20`

Answer (score 1):

In this answer I assume that your direct parent is always in a row above your own as it is what your expected output and your diagramm suggests.

With this hypothesis, we can, for each row, take the closest row with a level below the row :

```
import pandas as pd

data={"Symbol":["A", "A01", "A01B", "A01B 1/00", "A01B 1/02", "A01B 1/022", "B"], "level":[2,4,5,7,8,9,2]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df['Parent'] = ''

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # We look at the potential parents
    potential_parents = df.loc[df.index.isin([x for x in range(index)]) & (df['level'] < row['level']), 'Symbol']
    # And we take the last one as our parent
    if len(potential_parents) == 0: 
        df.loc[index, 'Parent'] = ''
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'Parent'] = potential_parents.iloc[-1]
```

Output :

```
       Symbol  level     Parent
0           A      2           
1         A01      4          A
2        A01B      5        A01
3   A01B 1/00      7       A01B
4   A01B 1/02      8  A01B 1/00
5  A01B 1/022      9  A01B 1/02
6           B      2
```

Comment: This almost works, but as soon as the next level 2 symbol is processed, error `IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` appears. There are 8 level 2 symbols and they have no parent. Code needs to account for the multiple level 2 symbols.

Comment: i guess something like `if len(potential_parents) == 0: df.loc[index, 'Parent'] = ''` might work alright.

Comment: Good idea, I edited my answer and tested it on a simple example. It seems to work

Comment: I don't think we need the first `if` statement. Just check the length of `potential_parents` and if it is 0, set that symbol's parent to `''`, else `potential_parents.iloc[-1]`

Comment: Is there any way to speed up the generation of `potential_parents`? Maybe something that looks in the range of only the rows of the first above level 2? A symbols that starts with B will never have a parent that starts with A. Further, level 19 symbols will have a very long `potent_parent` list.

Comment: You could think of this list as 8 separate trees... What if we made a list of the indicesof each level 2 symbols, and limit the df range we seach for `potential_parents` by this list?

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in a chat : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194892/level-problem

Comment: We missed each other on chat. Here is my idea, break df into sub-df at each level 2. Run the code above to get the parents, and then combine each sub-df