# Sum values of parent nodes in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df(small portion below). I am trying to add an additional tw0 columns `rolled_doc_cnt` & `rolled_doc_cnt_all` that contains the sum of  `doc_cnt`/`doc_cnt_all` for the current row and all of its children. In the very limited rows below, `df.at[0,'rolled_doc_cnt'] = 1317` & `df.at[0,'rolled_doc_cnt_all'] = 3540`

```py
    SYMBOL  level   not-allocatable additional-only doc_cnt doc_cnt_all parent
0   A   2   True    False   0   0   
1   A01 4   True    False   0   0   A
2   A01B    5   True    False   0   0   A01
3   A01B   1/00 7   False   False   198 244 A01B
4   A01B   1/02 8   False   False   230 538 A01B   1/00
5   A01B   1/022    9   False   False   83  238 A01B   1/02
6   A01B   1/024    9   False   False   28  63  A01B   1/02
7   A01B   1/026    9   False   False   100 120 A01B   1/02
8   A01B   1/028    9   False   False   27  82  A01B   1/02
9   A01B   1/04 9   False   False   29  54  A01B   1/02
10  A01B   1/06 8   False   False   78  508 A01B   1/00
11  A01B   1/065    9   False   False   118 150 A01B   1/06
12  A01B   1/08 9   False   False   71  326 A01B   1/06
13  A01B   1/10 9   False   False   14  30  A01B   1/06
14  A01B   1/12 9   False   False   24  86  A01B   1/06
15  A01B   1/14 9   False   False   44  131 A01B   1/06
16  A01B   1/16 8   False   False   159 518 A01B   1/00
17  A01B   1/165    9   False   False   50  114 A01B   1/16
18  A01B   1/18 9   False   False   64  338 A01B   1/16
```

I got some help creating the `parent` column [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56368124/adding-a-column-to-a-dataframe-containing-the-symbol-of-the-parent-node/56591975#56591975).

```py
def GetParent():
    # level      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19, 20
    hierarchy = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 5, 7, 8, 9,
                 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
    parent = ['']*len(hierarchy)

    def func(row):
        # print(row)
        symbol, level = row[['SYMBOL', 'level']]

        parent_level = hierarchy[level]
        parent_symbol = parent[parent_level]

        parent[level] = symbol

        return pd.Series([parent_symbol], index=['parent'])

    return func


# create a column with the parents
st = time()
parents = dfa.apply(GetParent(), axis=1)
dfa = pd.concat([dfa, parents], axis=1)
print((time()-st)/60, 'minutes elapsed')
```

I tried to debug this code in spyder so I could see how the list `parent` changes as I advance rows of the df, but I cannot figure out how to jump into the function `GetParent()` without also jumping into the pandas function `apply()`. Jumping into `apply()` eventually leads me to a recursion error.

I tried to make a few modification to `GetParents()` to also keep track of the document counts of each symbol at each level, but then I realized that I was keeping track of the document counts for the parent nodes, but not the children. So, with the df above, how would I be able to create something like the following df?

```
    SYMBOL  level   not-allocatable additional-only doc_cnt doc_cnt_all parent  rolled_doc_cnt  rolled_doc_cnt_all
0   A   2   TRUE    FALSE   0   0       1317    3540
1   A01 4   TRUE    FALSE   0   0   A   1317    3540
2   A01B    5   TRUE    FALSE   0   0   A01 1317    3540
3   A01B   1/00 7   FALSE   FALSE   198 244 A01B    1317    3540
4   A01B   1/02 8   FALSE   FALSE   230 538 A01B   1/00 497 1095
5   A01B   1/022    9   FALSE   FALSE   83  238 A01B   1/02 83  238
6   A01B   1/024    9   FALSE   FALSE   28  63  A01B   1/02 28  63
7   A01B   1/026    9   FALSE   FALSE   100 120 A01B   1/02 100 120
8   A01B   1/028    9   FALSE   FALSE   27  82  A01B   1/02 27  82
9   A01B   1/04 9   FALSE   FALSE   29  54  A01B   1/02 29  54
10  A01B   1/06 8   FALSE   FALSE   78  508 A01B   1/00 349 1231
11  A01B   1/065    9   FALSE   FALSE   118 150 A01B   1/06 118 150
12  A01B   1/08 9   FALSE   FALSE   71  326 A01B   1/06 71  326
13  A01B   1/10 9   FALSE   FALSE   14  30  A01B   1/06 14  30
14  A01B   1/12 9   FALSE   FALSE   24  86  A01B   1/06 24  86
15  A01B   1/14 9   FALSE   FALSE   44  131 A01B   1/06 44  131
16  A01B   1/16 8   FALSE   FALSE   159 518 A01B   1/00 273 970
17  A01B   1/165    9   FALSE   FALSE   50  114 A01B   1/16 50  114
18  A01B   1/18 9   FALSE   FALSE   64  338 A01B   1/16 64  338
```

> **Also feel free to tell me that the way I am trying to do this is not optimal and suggest another way**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function to get parent symbol (*GetParent*) can be simpified a bit:

```
def GetParent():
    hierarchy = [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10,
                 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
    parent = ['']*len(hierarchy)
    def func(row):
        symbol, level = row[['SYMBOL', 'level']]
        parent_level = hierarchy[level]
        parent_symbol = parent[parent_level]
        parent[level] = symbol
        return parent_symbol
    return func
```

i.e. it returns just the *parent_symbol* (not *Series*) and then it can be
applied with **direct creation** of the target column:

```
dfa['parent'] = dfa.apply(GetParent(), axis=1)
```

I tried this function on your sample data and got **no error**.

Note that *GetParent* is able to process the hierarchy up to 20 levels,
so maybe the source of your error is that your full data has **more**
hierarchy levels?

You didn't write anything where this error occured and what was the error message.
Start looking for the error cause from this point.

Another hint: Start from running this code on some initial part of your
data (e.g. the first half). The goal is to find the source row, on which
the error occurs. Then look **very thoroughly** at this row (and a bit
before it). This is likely to give you some clue about the reason of error.

## Edit

I came up with a solution that should work regardless of the hierarchy depth.

```
def GetParent():
    par = {0: ''}
    def func(row):
        symbol, level = row[['SYMBOL', 'level']]
        parLevel = level - 2 if level in [2, 4, 7] else level - 1
        parSym = par[parLevel]
        par[level] = symbol
            return parSym
    return func
```

Note than the issus of "missing hierarchy levels" is addressed in:

```
parLevel = level - 2 if level in [2, 4, 7] else level - 1
```

which returns *level - 2* for levels "just after" the missing levels
and *level - 1* for all other levels.

The parent symbol is kept in an "internal" dictionary, so there is no problem
with list index out of bounds.

The apply this function just as above, directly creating the target column.

## Edit 2

I see that you managed to compute ancestors, so now how to compute sums
of the columns of interest.

As far as operations on tree structures in *Pandas* are concerned,
I found an interesting piece of code in *StackOverflow* on page:

[Hierarchical data: efficiently build a list of every descendant for each node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46722740/hierarchical-data-efficiently-build-a-list-of-every-descendant-for-each-node)

Copy from there *list_ancestors* function and 2 other functions
used by it, namely *trace_nodes* and *numpy_col_inner_many_to_one_join*.

I will not repeat this code here.

Then run:

```
links = list_ancestors(dfa[['SYMBOL', 'parent']].values)
```

*list_ancestors* function generates a DataFrame, with *descendant*
and *ancestor* columns, including "links" between an ancestor and descendant
**at any depth** (till now you had only **direct** descendants).

To add *SYMBOL*, *doc_cnt* and *doc_cnt_all* columns, run:

```
links2 = pd.merge(links, dfa[['SYMBOL', 'doc_cnt', 'doc_cnt_all']],
    left_on='descendant', right_on='SYMBOL', copy=False)
```

And now start summing:

```
s1 = links2.groupby('ancestor')['doc_cnt', 'doc_cnt_all'].apply(sum)
s2 = dfa[['SYMBOL', 'doc_cnt', 'doc_cnt_all']].set_index('SYMBOL')
s3 = pd.concat([s1, s2]).groupby(level=0).apply(sum)
```

A bit of explanation:

- *s1* contains sums (of both columns of interest) for all
  **descendants** (at any depth), but without "own" values
  for these columns.
- *s2* in turn contains just the "missing" own values.
- *s3* sums these values.

The only 2 steps remaining to do are:

- change column names to the target names,
- join *dfa* with *s3*.

The code to do it is:

```
s3.columns=['rolled_doc_cnt', 'rolled_doc_cnt_all']
dfa.join(s3, on='SYMBOL')
```

For your test data, I got just the expected result.